# Here post method is not working properly ,when it push to the server,but in local host it is working properly

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-models

Here post method is not working properly when it push to the server,but in local host it is working properly.When it run in server,it will produce else case response like  'return HttpResponse("faild")',but  run in localhost it will produce, response like 'return HttpResponse(received_json_data)',can solve this issue.

values

```
[ 
{
    "user": 3,
    "news_category": 1,
    "sub_category": [1, 2]

}
]
```

urls.py

```
url(r'savesubcategory', csrf_exempt(views.savesubcategory), name='savesubcategory')
```

views.py

```py
import json
def savesubcategory(request):

    print "==============================="
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "++++++++++++++++++"

        received_json_data = json.loads(request.body)

        store_list = []
        for item in received_json_data:

            id =  item['user']
            name = User.objects.get(id=id)
            print name
            id = item['category']
            categ = Category.objects.get(id=id)
            for ite in item['sub_category']:
                subcat = SubCategory.objects.get(id=ite)
                print subcat
                # print name ," -- ", categ , "--",ite
                savecat = SavingCategoryandPreferences(user = name ,category = categ 
                 ,subcategories = subcat)
                savecat.save()



        return HttpResponse(received_json_data)
    return HttpResponse("faild")
```

Response in case of server

```
faild
```

I want response like ,

```
{
 'sub_category': [1, 2], 
 'user': 6, 
 'news_category': 3
}
```

Comment: You should post the full stack trace error you are getting on amazon. I'm pretty sure its something to do with your server environment more than anything else.

Comment: I think the only problem is, you are not making a POST request.